# My Java application can't compile

Tags: java

Here is my program as it is right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelfAssessment
{

 public static void main(int num, int counter, String str)
 {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    SelfAssessment.function1(num);
    SelfAssessment.function2(str);

 }

 //Collatz function
public static int function1(int num) (Collatz conjecture)
 {
     if(num < 1)
     {
         return -1;
     }
     else if(num >= 1)
     {
         while(num>=1)
         {
            if(num%2 == 1)
            {
             num = (num*3)+1;
             System.out.println(num);
            }
         else if(num%2 == 0  && num != 1)
         {
            num = num/2;
            System.out.println(num);
         }
        }
}
     return num;
 }

public static int function2(String str) (method to count up the lower-case e's and upper-case d's in a string)
 {
    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    str = in.NextLine();
    char ch;
    int lowereCount;
    int upperDCount;
    if(ch = 'e')
    {
        lowereCount++;
    }
    else if(ch='D')
    {
        upperDCount++;
    }
 }

public static int function3(int arr[], int findNum, int arraySize) (method to search for a certain character and return it (if found)
 {
    System.out.println("Enter numbers into array:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    for(int x=0; x<2; i++)
    {
        arraySize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<arraySize;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
     for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
     {
         if(arr[i] == findNum)
         {
             return i;
         }
         else if(arr[i] == findNum)
         {
             return -1;
         }
     }
 }
}
```

The issues I am having right now (at least the ones I can think of off the top of my head) are the following:

1. When trying to run it, it says it cannot find class `SelfAssessment`
2. In method `function3`, it says that it cannot find `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedStreamReader`

I know there are some more errors too, but I just can't think about them right now.

Could someone also check over my code to see if there are any other errors too?

Comment: Do you use an IDE like Eclipse ? It would be faster than asking on SO...

Comment: For question 1: how are you trying to run this program? For question 2: You haven't imported the package where you can find those classes. As noted by @Julien it will be faster if you first work in an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans (I heavily recommend this if you're in learning phase).

Comment: _Could someone also check over my code to see if there are any other errors too?_ You should do that, we can help you solving errors, but you should _find_ them, it's your application, not ours, you should debug, not us.

Comment: `public static void main(int num, int counter, String str)` How do you expect your program to get here?

Comment: use == to compare and you have to initialize variables before incrementing them.Make sure your functions return a value if have given a return type.

Comment: Are those dangling parentheticals supposed to be comments? Use `//` to set off comments in your code...

Comment: You are downvoted since it looks like you have not spent even few minutes reading your code or compiler messages. Some problems are: missing imports, 'kind of' comments starting with left paren, missing variables, strange 'if' statements that have same condition, within if and else ...... bla bla bla...incorrect main method...

Answer (score 3):

- > When trying to run it, it says it cannot find class SelfAssessment

Probably it is because of the later problem.

- > In method function3, it says that it cannot find InputStreamReader and BufferedStreamReader

You should insert to the top level

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedStreamReader;
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. When trying to run it, it says it cannot find class SelfAssessment

When JVM loads your class it looks for `public static void main(String[] args)`. 
You are missing it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

You have

```
public static void main(int num, int counter, String str){}
```

**For your second issue;** 
Please import the following;

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedStreamReader;
```

Comment: Wow.  Should have know that the main is just like that.  Also, I've now modified the program as I figured out that I don't need user input.  But now, when I try to run the first function, it just keeps on looping.  Would I need to have a for loop in this function (Collatz function) instead of a while loop?

Comment: @DanGoWildCzarnecki Yes.. Consider using a for loop there. Your while loop checks if the num >= 1 and num = num/2; will never return 0once in the while loop. You need to change it to num > 1 and not >=. Hope this helps. Also if the answer was helpful, close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not compile - read compiler messages top to bottom. They say exactly what is wrong.